# Valor desparece del input al dar click

Tags: php, html

tengo este campo que trae la info de una tabla de base de datos y funciona me trae la info correctamente, pero al momento de darle clic la información desaparece como si fuera un placeholder.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row->r_address;?>" name="r_address" required>
```

Que puedo hacer ahí?

Comment: No es posible darte una solucion sin todo el codigo PHP detras del input

Comment: pues la configuración va en el input no? porque la info llega bien, solo que el value desparece al darle clic al campo

Comment: No tendras algun evento escuchando por ahi en tu codigo html? pues es muy raro que suceda eso, prueba en otro navegador